# Can the HubTile Source property be set to a GIF?

Tags: windows-phone-7, silverlight-toolkit

I'm building an app that generates a grid of `HubTile` objects from the [Silverlight Toolkit](http://silverlight.codeplex.com/) representing people, with the `Source` property being set to a URL for their profile picture that's returned from a web service. If the person hasn't uploaded a profile picture, the URL that's returned is a GIF for a generic profile picture. It appears that the `HubTile` simply ignores the `Source`, because the image isn't being displayed. I've verified that the image exists at the provided URL. Are GIF's simply an unsupported image type for the `HubTile`? Unfortunately, the [documentation](http://silverlight.codeplex.com/documentation) on Codeplex is empty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, GIF images are not supported. From ["Tiles Overview for Windows Phone"](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh202948%28v=VS.92%29.aspx):

> Tile images can be either a .jpg or .png file

If you are referring to the `HubTile` control, it uses an `Image` under the hood which does not support GIFs either. As per [Supported Media Codecs for Windows Phone](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff462087%28v=VS.92%29.aspx)

> This file type [GIF] is unsupported by the Silverlight Image element

Comment: Thanks, Richard. That documentation is for the tiles displayed on the Start screen. I'm asking about the HubTile object included in the Silverlight Toolkit. I suspect the answer is the same, but I'll update my question to be more clear about that.